# How to associate 2 many_to_many relationship in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

How do you associate a double many_to_many relationship? and also, what is it called? I know that there's no "double" many_to_many.

So have these models in rails, a `User`, `Role`, `UserRole`, `Menu`, `RoleMenu`.

A user can access menus depending on the roles. On console, I can do this `User.first.roles.first.menus`. My question is there a way to do like this `User.first.menus`, so it'll shorten? How do you associate `User` to `Menu`? What should I add to my models? what migration should I create?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_roles
  has_many :roles, through: :user_roles
end

class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :email
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_roles
  has_many :users, through: :user_roles

  has_many :role_menus
  has_many :menus, through: :role_menus
end

class CreateRoles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :roles do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

```
class UserRole < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
end

class CreateUserRoles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :user_roles do |t|
      t.belongs_to :user
      t.belongs_to :role
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

```
class Menu < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :role_menus
  has_many :roles, through: :role_menus
end

class CreateMenus < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :menus do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

```
class RoleMenu < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :role
  belongs_to :menu
end

class CreateRoleMenus < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :role_menus do |t|
      t.belongs_to :role
      t.belongs_to :menu
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean `User.first.menus` instead of `User.menus` ? Because, latter can't be achieved as you are trying to access `menus` through `User` class (which is more of a `scope` implementation) and not the particular user.

For the first case, as I can see that you are already aware of the [`has_many, through`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) association. We will use the same to achieve that. Following should work.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_roles
  has_many :roles, through: :user_roles
  has_many :menus, through: :roles
end
```

> How do you associate a double many_to_many relationship? and also, what is it called? I know that there's no "double" many_to_many.

Well, yes, there's nothing called double many to many association but it is more aptly called multiple or nested many to many relation/association. And as mentioned above, it can be achieved through `has_many, through`

Comment: opps. my bad. thank you for pointing that out. yes your answer worked. thank you so much. I gave up actually thought this would be impossible on rails. thank you thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :user_roles
      has_many :roles, through: :user_roles
      has_many :menus, through: :roles
    end
```

adding another has_many.. through should work

Comment: my dude. sorry bro he got the first answer but thank you for this my guy.